# Explicitly set key and value for a select

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I explicitly set the key and value in a hash and then use those in a select?  I have a Link model where external links can be saved.  A link has a title and a url.  I want to use the title as the key and the url as the value.

## --------------------- UPDATE -------------------------

This work..

```
links = Link.all

link_array = []

links.each do |link| 
  link_array << [link.title,link.url]
end
```

But, now here is the hitch.  I want to join this array to another array so that two models can be selectable from a single form select.  Like this...

```
a = PagesController.action_methods
   # this grabs each action from the pages controller that will later be used as a route

b = a.select {|s| s.include? "callback"}
c = a - b
   # b and c removes any position in the array that includes the word 'callback' so that only actions defined in the controller are returned

links = Link.all

link_array = []

links.each do |link| 
  link_array << [link.title,link.url]
end

@all_links = c + link_array
   # desired result is an array used in a single form select containing both external links and internal links
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what I want it to do.  Maybe there is a better way.

```
 a = PagesController.action_methods
 b = a.select {|s| s.include? "callback"}
 c = a - b
 @c_array = []
 c.each do |p|
   @c_array << [p, "#{p}_path"]
 end

 links = Link.all
 @link_array = []
 links.each do |link| 
   @link_array << [link.title, link.url]
 end

 @all_links = @c_array + @link_array
```

Results in a single array containing both internal routes (to page actions) and external links to urls.  Now, in a third model I can have a string column titled :pathto and store either a route (as a string) or a url.  Then, in a helper do this:

```
    def send_route(pathto)
      if pathto.include? "http"
        pathto # just go to the url
      else
        self.send( pathto ) # create a route from the string stored in the db .. i.e. "home_path"
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're going for, but it seems like you're looking for something like this:

```
Link.where(title: url)
```

...where url is some local variable. This will generate a SQL statement similar to the following:

```
SELECT * FROM links WHERE title='yoururl'
```